# Signature validation failed. Reference validation failed

Tags: onelogin

I am using onelogin for SAML as SP. I was able to get the response XML. But the validation of the SAML response is failing due to

```
Signature validation failed. Reference validation failed
```

I tried to check the XML via [the online tool](https://www.samltool.com/validate_response.php) but got the same error.

Could you please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Still waiting for some clue what might be wrong. Would be really helpful to have some direction.Thanks

Comment: Can you share IDP you are using? Also SAML Request and Response as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens when the SP is not able to validate the Signature included in the SAMLResponse.

In order to fix it, verify that the public certificate of the settings that you have register for the IdP is the right value.

One easy way to verify it is to record the SAML flow with the SAMLTracer Firefox plugin, and then review the value of the x509Certificate value element of the Signature matches the value you have in your SAML toolkit setting.

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. I have another question related to SP intiated logout. I will ask as a separate post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AjayKumarVasireddy did you do any changes to make it work?

Comment: @asgs Sorry. It's been a long time. So, totally unlearned.

Comment: @AjayKumarVasireddy :-) no worries. in my case, it was timing related issues plus the incorrect X509 certificate public key that caused it

Answer (score 0):

Along with the certificate check if you have enabled *Response Signature Verification* to only Assertion or both Assertion and response. In my case, i had to set verification *Response Signature Verification* only to Assertion

Comment: I did but still getting the same error.